# How to find the nearest subway station of each house

Tags: python, r, location

I have a huge data-set A of latitude and longitude of each house/apt in NewYorkCity.
And a data-set B of latitude and longitude of each subway station/entrance in NYC too.

For each house I want to identify the nearest subway station and the distance to that station.
The problem is that I have tens of thousands of houses, and hundreds of subway stations. If I am going to calculate the distance for each houses, it's time wasting.
What is the fastest way to identify the nearest one?
Is there any packages in R or Python can help me do it fast?

Answer (score 1):

If each row represents a home and each column represents a station, you can simply calculate the distance matrix and find the minimum value of each row.

The `geosphere` package is helpful here because it will calculate distances based on coordinates

You will notice that I put the longitude first, the distance function `distHaversine` orders it this way.

Please [read about the package here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/geosphere/vignettes/geosphere.pdf). I just followed the directions for the example.

Example:

```
cities <- data.frame(city = c('Miami', 'Atlanta', 'New York', 'Los Angeles'),
                     lon = c(-80.1917, -84.387982, -74.005941, -118.243685),
                     lat = c(25.76168, 33.748995, 40.712784, 34.052234),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

stations <- data.frame(station = c('Orlando', 'Richmond', 'Nashville'),
                       lon = c(-81.379236, -77.436048, -86.781602),
                       lat = c(28.538335, 37.540725, 36.162664),
                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
cities
#          city        lon      lat
# 1       Miami  -80.19170 25.76168
# 2     Atlanta  -84.38798 33.74900
# 3    New York  -74.00594 40.71278
# 4 Los Angeles -118.24368 34.05223

stations
#     station       lon      lat
# 1   Orlando -81.37924 28.53834
# 2  Richmond -77.43605 37.54073
# 3 Nashville -86.78160 36.16266

library(geosphere)
dist_mat <- mapply(function(lon, lat, cty) distHaversine(c(lon, lat), cty), stations[,2], stations[,3], list(cities[-1]))
min_dist <- apply(dist_mat, 1, which.min)
cbind(city=cities[,1], closest_station=stations[min_dist,1])
#      city          closest_station
# [1,] "Miami"       "Orlando"      
# [2,] "Atlanta"     "Nashville"    
# [3,] "New York"    "Richmond"     
# [4,] "Los Angeles" "Nashville"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try with a Quadtree.

Both R and python have implementations:

- R: SearchTrees
- Python: pyqtree

Comment: thank you I look up pyqtree python package, but I didn't find anything useful for my case. Can you please show me more information ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> If I am going to calculate the distance for each houses, it's time
>   wasting.

not really that's what computers are for.  I can't imagine this taking hours on a common desktop.

this is untested, consider it pseudocode:

```
# distance between points is sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)

houses = [[32,54],[3,2],[15,16]]
subways = [[123,2],[54,3],[56,6],[54,32],[1,65],[43,1],[13,16],[21,6],[5,1]]

distances = []
for i in range(len(houses)):
      distances.append([])
      for j in range(len(subways)):
          delta_x = house[i][0]-subway[j][0]
          delta_y = house[i][1]-subway[j][1]
          distance = (delta_x**2 + delta_y**2)**(0.5)
          distances[i].append(distance)
      min_idx = distances.index(min(distances))

      print 'closest subway to house number %s at %s is subway number %s at %s' (
          i, house[i], min_idx, subways[min_idx])
```

I'd wager for 50k houses and 500 subways you'd have an answer in under an hour.